# Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly. But the assembly is there

Tags: asp.net

I do not understand from where this problem comes. I have the correct assembly in the Bin, the same is correctly referenced in the web.config

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.1.14.804, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=A9D7983DFCC261BE"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
....
<httpHandlers>
  .........
  <add path="Telerik.ReportViewer.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.HttpHandler, Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.1.14.804, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" validate="true"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

the particular feature object of the error is working on my developing machine but on the production server I get this error!

```
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Reporting, Version=8.1.14.804, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Source Error:
Line%70<td%class="leftGridColumn">&nbsp;</td>
Line%71:<td%class="centerGridColumn">
Line%72<telerik:ReportViewer%ID="ReportViewer1"%runat="server"%Width="100%"%Height="660px"%ShowExportGroup="False"%
Line%73:</td>
Line%74:<td%class="rightGridColumn">&nbsp;</td>
```

Any hint will be really appreciated I do not know what else do do to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is 'Are you sure you are using the correct/compatible version of the .Net Framework?'. I had a problem a while back when using Asp.Net MVC where it didn't like 4.5, so i had to create a 4.0 project.

**EDIT**

Just found this on an old blog:

The original warning you receive explains that you should register the handler for the web report viewer in the httphandlers section in the web config. However if you're hosting the application in IIS7, there is a different section to add the handler to, namely the `<system.webServer>\<handlers>` section:

```
<system.webServer>  
    <handlers>  
       <add name="Telerik.ReportViewer.axd_*" path="Telerik.ReportViewer.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.HttpHandler, Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=3.2.9.1211, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"   />  
    </handlers>  
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />    
</system.webServer>
```

"it clearly states that it cannot find a necessary assembly you're referencing. During the installation of Telerik Reporting on your machine, the Telerik assemblies were added to GAC. When deploying a Web Site project the assemblies from the GAC are not copied automatically, so you need to copy the assemblies manually from the installation’s Telerik Reporting /bin folder to the bin folder of your application on the server. Full step by step instructions on deploying are included in the Deploying Applications using Telerik Reporting help article."

Here's the link: http://www.telerik.com/forums/web-reportviewer-error

Comment: Thanks but this is not the case. The website is running fine. It is only a specific page where a Reportviewer is used that is giving the problem.

Comment: Thanks. The handler is also there already with the correct assembly referenced. :-(

Comment: "The Telerik Team clearly tells you to "copy the assemblies manually from the installation’s Telerik Reporting /bin folder to the bin folder of your application on the server"

To automate this process, under your project Reference, right click on Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms and click Properties. Make sure that the Copy Local property is set to True. And do the same for the Telerik.Reporting reference."

Comment: I did it straight from the Telerik Bin.

Comment: there could be a mismatch between assemblies: a DLL referenced from an assembly doesn't have a method signature that's expected.

Clean the solution, rebuild everything, and try again.